# Custom Email Appenders for sending log4j errors not returning complete stacktrace

Tags: grails, logging, groovy, log4j

I am writing my own CustomEmailAppender to send Emails for the error generated.

Code looks like:

```
class CustomEmailAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
   def ctx = ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getMainContext()
   def mailService = ctx.getBean('mailService')
   def springSecurityService = ctx.getBean('springSecurityService')
   def executorService = ctx.getBean('executorService')


  public static void register() {
    CustomEmailAppender appender = new CustomEmailAppender()
    Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender)
    Logger.getLogger("StackTrace").addAppender(appender)
  }

/**
 * Constructor with default values.
 */
    public CustomEmailAppender() {
      setThreshold(Level.ERROR)
      setLayout(new PatternLayout("%c{2} %m%n"))
    }

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
 @Override
    public void append(final LoggingEvent event) {

      if (!event.getLevel().isGreaterOrEqual(Level.ERROR)) {
          return
       }

      event.getThreadName()
      event.getNDC()
      event.getMDCCopy()
      sendErrorEmail(layout.format(event))
    }

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton#close()
 */
  public synchronized void close() {
      closed = true
  }

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton#requiresLayout()
 */
  public boolean requiresLayout() {
      return true
  }

  void sendErrorEmail(String errorLogs) {
      println "errorLogs.." + errorLogs
  }
}
```

Here errorLogs is returning only log.error message, not complete stacktrace.

I want complete stacktrace to be emailed.

Can anyone tell me what more enhancements i need to do on the above code to get the
Complete stacktrace in errorLogs parameter.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass event parameter from sendErrorEmail method above && use the following code in

```
    void sendErrorEmail(LoggingEvent event) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer()
    String header = layout.getHeader()
    if(header != null){
        buffer.append(header)
    }
    buffer.append(layout.format(event))
    if(layout.ignoresThrowable()) {
        String[] s = event.getThrowableStrRep()
        if (s != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
                buffer.append(s[j])
                buffer.append(Layout.LINE_SEP);
            }
        }
    }
    String footer = layout.getFooter()
    if (footer != null) {
        buffer.append(footer)
    }
}
```

buffer varible will return you the complete stacktrace.